# Javascript Information Needed

Tags: javascript

Looking for a little guidance. I know its something small and dumb but I'm completely drawing a blank at this point and could use some help. I'm trying to create a mobile app for my class that needs a dynamic table for my results. I'm attempting to create a user input to select a number of "Random powerball tickets" and the table would give "Ticket 1 / Random Numbers." I have managed to create the random number generator onclick but cant for the life of me figure out the rest.

HTML- I dont remember how to connect the user input to the button and repeat x amount of times to match.

```
<div data-role="content">
    <p>This will be a simple application that provide generated powerball numbers between 1-69.</p>
    </div>
    <div>
    <button id="button" onClick="winningNumbers()" >Powerball Numbers</button>
    </div>
    <p id="outcome"></p>
    <table id="data">
        </table>
```

Current Javascript

```
var powerball;

function powerballNumbers(max) {
  var ranNum = Math.floor((Math.random() * max) + 1);
  return ranNum;
}

function main() {
  powerball = [];
  for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    powerball.push(powerballNumbers(69));
  }
  powerball.push(powerballNumbers(26));
}



function winningNumbers() {
  main();
  var totalTickets = document.getElementById("outcome");

  totalTickets.innerText = powerball;

}
```

Thinking of something like this for the table but know it's not correct

```
function updateTable(ticketNumber, powerballNumber) {
  var dataTable = document.getElementById("data");
  dataTable.innerHTML = "";

  // create rows of data based on given arrays
  (Not sure what to put here)
    

  // create header row
  var thead = dataTable.createTHead();
  var row = thead.insertRow(0);
  var tableHeaders = ["Ticket", "Numbers"];
  for (var i = 0; i < tableHeaders.length; i++) {
    var headerCell = document.createElement("th");
    headerCell.innerHTML = tableHeaders[i];
    row.appendChild(headerCell);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure of what your end goal is, but the best I understand is you want to generate some tickets with an ID, and each ticket has 5 numbers? If so, I simply generated a ticket ID, and 5 numbers to go with that ticket. Then in the update table function, I've simplified it so it can focus on just appending new rows. If I've missed the mark please comment below and/or update your question.

Just some side comments.

- Avoid using attributes for click events, it's unreliable at best.
- Don't hestiate to use HTML when HTML is the answer. Your original update table method was going to build out a table? It only adds a headache, not ease.
- Good job on leveraging the tools `<table>` gives us!

```js
var powerball;

function powerballNumbers(max) {
  var ranNum = Math.floor((Math.random() * max) + 1);
  return ranNum;
}

function main() {
  let i = 0
  interval = setInterval(function() {
    updateTable(powerballNumbers(9999), [powerballNumbers(69),
      powerballNumbers(69),
      powerballNumbers(69),
      powerballNumbers(69),
      powerballNumbers(69)
    ]);
    i++;
    if (i > 5) {
      clearInterval(interval);
    }
  }, 500)
}


function winningNumbers() {
  main();
  var totalTickets = document.getElementById("outcome");

  totalTickets.innerText = powerball;
}

function updateTable(ticket, powerballNumber) {
  var dataTable = document.getElementById("data");

  let newRow = dataTable.insertRow();
  let ticketCell = newRow.insertCell();
  ticketCell.textContent = ticket;
  let numbers = newRow.insertCell();
  numbers.textContent = powerballNumber.join(", ");
}
```

```html
<div data-role="content">
  <p>This will be a simple application that provide generated powerball numbers between 1-69.</p>
</div>
<div>
  <button id="button" onClick="winningNumbers()">Powerball Numbers</button>
</div>
<p id="outcome"></p>
<table id="data" border=1>
  <thead>
    <tr>Ticket Number</tr>
    <tr>Numbers</tr>
  </thead>
</table>
```